# How can I build an Apache Airflow production image using Breeze without getting a gpg error?

Tags: airflow

I am following the [Breeze instructions for building a production image](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/BREEZE.rst#building-production-images) and running the following command:

```
$ ./breeze build-image --production-image --additional-extras "jira"
```

Unfortunately I get the following error:

```
+ ./scripts/docker/install_mysql.sh dev
gpg: keybox '/tmp/tmp.acAI8eVGuD/pubring.kbx' created
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Address family not supported by protocol
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out
gpg: keyserver receive failed: Connection timed out
gpg: WARNING: nothing exported
Warning: apt-key output should not be parsed (stdout is not a terminal)
gpg: no valid OpenPGP data found.
```

I am running from behind a firewall requiring an HTTP proxy to connect to the outside world. I see [this pull request](https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/11176) might fix my issue but I am not sure how.

Comment: The workaround I have so far is to use `--disable-mysql-client-installation`. Fortunately I don't need MySQL. However, this does not solve the issue if someone needs MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

I just created a pull request https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/12101 to fix this. After Debian 9 and according to the manual https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/apt/apt-key.8.en.html, instead of using "apt-key add" a keyring should be placed directly in the /etc/apt/trusted.gpg.d/ directory with a descriptive name and either "gpg" or "asc" as file extension. Also added better redirection on the apt-key list command.

Comment: Merged https://github.com/apache/airflow/pull/12101 into master.